# Why this code dont generate any error (Access Violation) and works ? (MyHelloVar.Close works like Self.Close)

Tags: delphi

Why this command is working like "Self.Close" or like that?

First, I think that was like this:

> MyHelloVar. {spaces...}      Close;

or be:

> Command 1:  MyHelloVar.    // but this wont compile it, or yes?

> Command 2:  {Self.} Close;

The "MyHelloVar" itself is behaving as if she were my variable (instance) of the main form.

Is it true what I'm understanding here?

unit Unit1;

```
interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants,
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
(* Summary:
  - RAD Studio 11.1 Alexandria
  - VCL Project 32bits (common case)
  - 1 form = my main form created automatically by IDE
  - 1 form = my second form not created automatically
  - 1 button to test!
*)

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyHelloVar: TForm;
begin
  // That's crazy behaviour!
  //
  MyHelloVar.Close; // this is close my "App" like "Self.Close" do it!
  //
end;

end.
```

Comment: Local variables of unmanaged types (like class types, like `TForm`) are uninitialized, so you are calling `TForm.Close` on a random pointer (whatever happens to be in your computer's RAM at that place). Then anything can happen. Different things can happen every time you run the code. This is a bug.

Comment: Interessant!!! I never had this case before!

Answer (score 1):

### Using Delphi 7

The last thing that was used in memory was the variable `Form1`. In your event handler method you just use the same datatype (that is `TForm`) for the last used memory - that's the only reason why it works: same data structure for the same position in memory.

It also works by adding more forms and using the same code there - the `MyHelloVar` variable will then point to `Form2`, `Form3` and so on (which can be easily debugged by evaluating the variable's property `.Name`, using *Run > Evaluate/Modify*). So, yes: it appears to work like `self`.

**However**, as soon as you use more variables in that method the fantasy world will break apart, f.e.:

```pas
var
  one, two,
  MyHelloVar: TForm;
begin
  self.Caption:= one.Caption+ two.Caption;
  MyHelloVar.Close();
end;
```

If you now evaluate `one` and `two` (and finally `MyHelloVar`) you'll see much different content and executing it will most likely crash your program. I also don't know why you ignore the compiler warnings which clearly tell you:

> [Warning] Unit1.pas(35) Variable 'one' might not have been initialized 
> [Warning] Unit1.pas(35) Variable 'two' might not have been initialized 
> [Warning] Unit1.pas(36) Variable 'MyHelloVar' might not have been initialized

It's not magic, just coincidence. Which you cannot rely on. I was able to reproduce this using Delphi 7, compiling a 32 bit executable under Win7x64.

### Using FPC/Lazarus

Lazarus 2.2.0 using FPC 3.2.2 will show the same compiler warning:

> unit1.pas(36,3) Warning: Local variable "MyHelloVar" does not seem to be initialized

...and evaluating that variable will already show it's pointing to a very different memory - as a result the program crashes at that point. This time it's also a 64 bit executable. So your magic trick won't even work with that compiler. Or platform.

Comment: > I also don't know why you ignore the compiler warnings which clearly tell you:....

I not ignoring nothing in question!
I just never faced this case!

using:
Integer(Pointer(Self)) and
Integer(Pointer(MyHelloVar)) it's possible see the same address used, BUT in my test I really didnt think that the code would valid at all. 
I would wait a logical "Access Violation"!

for this, it's right. 
It's a randomic in action  ;)))